# Search through a list or an array for existing string

Tags: c#, list

I need an array or list that contains names that the user will add to. I also need to perform a check that won't allow a name to be added if that name already exists. I know this should be fairly simple but I have not been able to find any solution.

Comment: Have you thought about the following `HashSet, Dictionary<string,string>, List<string>` where you could implement the `.Contains()` method or you can do Linq against it but I doubt you know Linq since you are asking this particular type of question

Comment: HashSet<string> is the best solution for the purpose, easy to use, high performance O(1) and it can even be made case insensitive if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may just be after:

```
if (list.Contains(name))
```

Or:

```
if (array.Contains(name))
```

It's as simple as that! Both `List<T>` and `T[]` implement the `IList<T>` interface with its [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/k5cf1d56.aspx) method. This is assuming you're happy with an exact match, of course. If you need something more complicated, I'd probably use `Any` from LINQ. For example:

```
if (array.Any(x => x.StartsWith(name))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashSet<string>`; `HashSet`'s are collections of unique elements. Their `.Add` method returns `true` if the element was added, and `false` otherwise.

If you cannot use such a data structure, then simply call `.Contains` on the list and pass in the element to be added - if it returns `true`, then do not add it. Otherwise, you're good to go and can append it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the list is instantiated:

```
//List<string> list
list.contains(specifiedstring)
```

Otherwise if it is a complex object with a string field - List then I would use:

```
//For a List<ClassA> list
var exists = list.Any(x => !String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x.StringAField) && 
                          x.StringAField.Equals(string));
```

This gives you the bool value to check in an if statement or other condition.